# Can not fetch data from <html:text>

Tags: java, arraylist, struts-1

I have written code in struts for fetch data from database, set in a list and show in .jsp page. I also want take some more data from user and work with it.
 My list and jsp is here

```
ArrayList area = new ArrayList();
session.setAttribute("areaList",area);
```

jsp page is

```
<html:form action="calculate.do?parameter=doCalculate" method="post">
    <logic:iterate id="rows" name="areaList" scope="session">
    <tr><td><html:text name="rows" property="userGroup"/></td>
        <td><html:text name="rows" property="totalArea"/></td>
        <td><html:text name="rows" property="areaComplete"/></td>
        <td><html:text name="rows" property="areaOccupied"/></td></tr>
    </logic:iterate>
<html:submit value="Calculate"/>
```

Action class:

```
ArrayList area = (ArrayList)session.getAttribute("areaList");
for (int i=0; i<area.size(); i++) {
    AreaDetails ad = (AreaDetails)area.get(i);
    System.out.println("UseGRp: "+ad.getUserGroup()+" Total Area:"+ad.getTotalArea()+" Complete :"+ad.getAreaComplete()+" Ocupaid: "+ad.getAreaOccupied());
```

But get null "ad.getTotalArea()" and "ad.getAreaComplete()".
What will be the solution??

Comment: Is it possible that the total and complete areas are simply missing, leading to `null` values?

Comment: I think you mismatch Area and AreaDetails . Check your classes type casting.

Comment: but i have get value in "ad.getUserGroup()" and "ad.getTotalArea()".

Comment: but not get the value for any <html:text>. what will be the problem??